# How do write a template which can decide which constructor to call?

Tags: c++

I'd like to be able to construct an A or B without having to think about the number of constructor arguments.

The second constructor is not legal C++ but I wrote it like this as an attempt to express what I want.

Is there an enable_if trick to selectively enable one of the constructors?

(e.g. depending on the number of constructor arguments of A and B.)

I need this to test about 15 classes with 1, 2 or 3 constructor arguments.

```
struct A
{
    A(int x)
    {
    }
};

struct B
{
    B(int x, int y)
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Adaptor // second constructor is illegal C++.
{
    T t;

    Adaptor(int x, int y)
        : t(x)
    {
    }

    Adaptor(int x, int y) // error: cannot be overloaded
        : t(x, y)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Adaptor<A> a(1,2);
    Adaptor<B> b(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `A::A` with one argument, and `B::B` with two arguments?

Comment: Why would you want to have to write `Adaptor<A> a(1,2)` if the `2` is simply to be discarded anyway?

Comment: I want to give A and B the same interface by wrapping them.

Comment: Can you modify your original constructors (A and B) to both take the maximum number of arguments (3 in this case). Then you can simply have your Adaptor(int x, int y, int z) : t(x,y,z) and throw away whatever values you don't want to initialize in the constructors of A and B instead of the Adaptor constructor?

Comment: @Yuushi Changing the constructors would be the obvious thing to do, but I don't want that. If the Adaptor class could wrap it without depending on any of the classes it wraps that would be cool, but it might require a template meta-programming Ninja.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variant of @Aaron's approach:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

enum EArity { EZero = 0, EOne, ETwo, EThree, Error };

template <typename T, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3> struct getArity
{
    static const EArity arity =
       std::is_constructible<T>::value             ? EZero  :
       std::is_constructible<T, A1>::value         ? EOne   :
       std::is_constructible<T, A1, A2>::value     ? ETwo   :
       std::is_constructible<T, A1, A2, A3>::value ? EThree : Error;
};

template <typename T, EArity A> struct Construct;

template <typename T> struct Construct<T, EZero>
{
    T t;

    template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
    Construct(A1 && a1, A2 && a2, A3 && a3) : t() { }
};

template <typename T> struct Construct<T, EOne>
{
    T t;

    template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
    Construct(A1 && a1, A2 && a2, A3 && a3) : t(std::forward<A1>(a1)) { }
};

// ...

template <typename T>
struct AdapterIntIntInt : Construct<T, getArity<T, int, int, int>::arity>
{
    Adapter(int a, int b, int c)
    : Construct<T, getArity<T, int, int, int>::arity>(a, b, c) { }
};

template <typename T, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
struct Adapter : Construct<T, getArity<T, A1, A2, A3>::arity>
{
    Adapter(A1 && a1, A2 && a2, A3 && a3)
    : Construct<T, getArity<T, A1, A2, A3>::arity>
      (std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2), std::forward<A3>(a3))
    { }
};
```

Comment: Do you know which compilers support `is_constructible` yet?

Comment: @DavidBrown: No, afraid not :-)

Comment: Not sure how useful this is, but here's some code to count the number of args in a constructor. Depends on typeof though - that g++ only, isn't it? http://ideone.com/y0Ich

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Yeah, you can do something like that. I was thinking about that initally, too, but I think `is_constructible` is a bit more elegant (assuming it's supported). You can substitute any version of `getArity` yourself, of course. [I'm also making a few changes as we speak, I hadn't tested this.]

Comment: It seems g++ 4.6 supports `is_constructible`, I'm not sure about clang, and MSVC does not support it yet.

Comment: I take it the `AdapterIntIntInt` is redundant in this answer code at the moment?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: it's just an example for how to use the `Construct` class. `AdapterIntIntInt` hardcodes the constructor types, while for `Adapter` you have to spell them out yourself.

Comment: This is really just an example approach. I think the proper way to do it would be to accept a variadic argument collection and a type, and call the constructor that accepts the most initial arguments. I just can't see at the moment how to do that without some extra indirection, which the present solution avoids entirely.

Comment: Now I'm still looking for a C++03 workaround for `std::is_constructible`.

Comment: @EddyPronk, the code I put on [ideone](http://ideone.com/y0Ich) is like `is_constructible`. It use SFINAE. For example in `template<typename C>
        static two& test(typeof((C(3,4))) * );`, the compiler attempts to construct the object with two integer parameters. If it fails, then SFINAE allows it to skip that and try later definitions of `test`. That code is basically C++03, but I think it relys on at least one g++ extension, typeof. I have no idea how to make a fully portable, strictly C++03, version. Do you know which compilers you'll be targetting?

Comment: Very nice. I'm targeting gcc and msvc. I still need to check if they agree.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

struct A {
    A(int) {}
};

struct B {
    B(int, int) {}
};

template <class T>
struct arg_count {
};

template <>
struct arg_count<A> {
    const static int count = 1;
};

template <>
struct arg_count<B> {
    const static int count = 2;
};

template <class T>
struct Adaptor : public T {
    template <class A1, class A2>
    Adaptor(A1 a1, A2 a2, typename boost::enable_if_c<arg_count<T>::count == 1, A1>::type* = 0) : T(a1) {}

    template <class A1, class A2>
    Adaptor(A1 a1, A2 a2, typename boost::enable_if_c<arg_count<T>::count == 2, A2>::type* = 0) : T(a1, a2) {}
};


int main() {
    Adaptor<A> a(1, 2);
    Adaptor<B> b(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: I like this better than the other template specialization solution because it separates the arg_count part. This is probably the best solution for C++03.

Comment: What does `A1` as second argument of `enable_if_c` mean?

Comment: The template parameter A1 is the type that enable_if_c::type yields when the condition is true. The default is void.

Comment: In this example they are both A1, but if you add a class C and extend this pattern to 3 parameters they need to be different. A1, A2, A3 works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use template specialization. The first Adaptor is the 'default' template, but the latter will be used only for `Adaptor<A>`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Adaptor
{
    T t;

    Adaptor(int x, int y)
        : t(x,y)
    {
    }


};

template<>
struct Adaptor<A> {
    A t;
    Adaptor(int x, int y)
        : t(x)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, but I have 15 classes I want to wrap, but I don't want to write 15 specializations, only 3 because the only difference is the 1, 2 or 3 arguments.